How to buy a consumable item in a MAUI app
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I want to allow users to buy consumables and in particular lives to play with the game.
Using the InAppBillingPlugin, I created in the stores (Apple Store, Google Play and Microsoft Store) the consumables. With the code in the plugin repository, I can retrieve the list of the consumables.

When I want to buy, I use the following code from this page:
public async Task<bool> PurchaseItem(string productId)
{
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;

    try
    {
        var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

        if (!connected)
        {
            //we are offline or can't connect, don't try to purchase
            return false;
        }

        // check purchases
        var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(
            productId, ItemType.InAppPurchaseConsumable);

        // possibility that a null came through.
        if (purchase == null)
        {
            // did not purchase
        }
        else if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
        {
            // purchased, we can now consume the item or do it later

            // only required on Android & Windows    
            var wasConsumed = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.
                ConsumePurchaseAsync(purchase.ProductId, 
                    purchase.TransactionIdentifier);

            if (wasConsumed)
            {
                // Consumed!!
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
    {
        // Billing Exception handle this based on the type
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + purchaseEx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Something else has gone wrong, log it
        Debug.WriteLine("Issue connecting: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }
}

Running this code, the result in the variable purchase is always null in Windows. Do you know how to fix it?
